# Cheerio direct child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, request, cheerio

Hey guys and ladies first of all this is my first question here in stackoverflow so don't be so hard on me..  but w/e :P.
I have a problem..
i'm totally new to web scraping and at the moment i have the problem that i can't select the right elements. My code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();
var port = 8000;

var url = "http://www.finanzparasiten.de/html/links/awd.html";

request(url, function (err, resp, body) {
    if(!err) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body)

        var test = $('body table table table > tbody > tr > td > p');
        console.log(test.html())   
        test.each(function (ii, asdf) {
            var rr = $(asdf).find("table").find("tr").first().find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            console.log(asdf);
        }) 
    } else {
        console.log("we encountered an error: " + err);
    }
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server is listening on ' + port);
```

It keeps logging NULL for the variable test.
It seems like cheerio has problems with the > selector. With jQuery this selection would work as expected.

Thanks to @logol's anwser i could solve the first problem but now i facing the problem that i have to select direct childs after body and it seems to bug as the tbody.. any1 got a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Original:**

as far as I remember (when I used cheerio the last time) tbody is not recognized in cheerio, just leave it and use this instead:

table > tr > td

PS: thead was working

**Update:**

it seems to work sometimes even with tbody, try this in REPL

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const html = '\
<!DOCTYPE html>\
<html>\
  <head>\
    <title>Cheerio Test</title>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <div id="#1">\
      <table>\
        <thead>\
          <tr>\
            <th>Month</th>\
            <th>Savings</th>\
          </tr>\
        </thead>\
        <tfoot>\
          <tr>\
            <td>Sum</td>\
            <td>180</td>\
          </tr>\
        </tfoot>\
        <tbody>\
          <tr>\
            <td>January</td>\
            <td>100</td>\
          </tr>\
          <tr>\
            <td>February</td>\
            <td>80</td>\
          </tr>\
        </tbody>\
      </table>\
    </div>\
  </body>\
</html>';
const dom = cheerio.load(html);

// not working:
let tds1 = dom('div#1 > table > tbody > tr > td').map(function () {
  return dom(this).text().trim();
}).get();

// working:
let tds2 = dom('table > tbody > tr > td').map(function () {
  return dom(this).text().trim();
}).get();

// not working:
let tds3 = dom('div#1 > table > tr > td').map(function () {
  return dom(this).text().trim();
}).get();

console.log(tds1);
console.log(tds2);
console.log(tds3);
```

Comment: wow that seems to work :O thank you could it be possible that body is also not recognized? e.g. body > div:last-of-type seems also failing

Comment: I played around a bit and sometimes it works sometimes not.. see user3366016 deeper investigation

Comment: what if I have multiple tables and I don't know the order of them beforehand, only what content they should have? this is way too hard-coded to access the specific table in my case. especially if there's table inside table.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Based on @logol's response, I checked the [docs for Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#selectors) and it says its selectors are built on CSSSelect Library.  Their [docs](https://github.com/fb55/css-select#supported-selectors) have a list of selectors. Child and Parent selectors are supported and it seems to imply all element selectors are too.  However, this g[ithub issue](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/143#issuecomment-104684742) flags the tbody issue.

**Original:**

Do you mean to have the duplicate tables listed in your selector and how you're printing it out in console.

Try this:

```
var test = $('body table > tbody > tr > td > p');
console.log(test.innerHTML)
```

The output of this on the webpage is:

```
<span class="TDheadlinebig">AWD - Allgemeiner
                Wirtschaftsdienst</span><span class="TDnormal"><br>
                </span><span class="TDheadlinenormal">zweitgrößte "Strukkibude"
                </span><span class="TDnormal"><br>
                </span>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but thats not the problem u could inpect the url if you want to. It happens for me for every direct selection. Maybe this was a bad selection but it is also NULL when i use ur selection.

Comment: with jquery yes. But as i mentioned i use cheerio for web scraping

Comment: @logol was onto something :)   I was not; but I added some docs and a github issue with the same tbody problem.

Comment: yes perfect :) but it seems like i happens also for body any1 got a workaround to directly select childs after body like $("body > div:not(:first-of-type)"); i need to select the direct divs and no possibility to select something else than body as parent...

Comment: Wasn't able to test this but may want to try loading the body then finding the divs and getting the first. `$('body').find('div').first()`  [github PR](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/141)